# ggplot overlay with data from different year error

Tags: r, ggplot2, code-formatting

I am using ggplot on for my data and my code is working fine

```
g<-ggplot(d=subset(d, !is.na(value)), aes(date, value, col = variable)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ lakename)+ labs(y="Concentration(ug/l)",x="year")+ scale_color_manual(name="Legend",labels = c("(No3+No2)-N_dry","NH4_dry"), values = c("blue","pink"))

g+theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12), axis.title=element_text(size=12,face="bold"))+ theme(legend.text=element_text(size=12))
```

but if I try to overlay ggplot with same data set but different years, it is giving me an error

I used g+geom_line to overlay it

```
g+geom_line(d=subset(d, !is.na(value)), aes(date, value, col = variable))+ geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ lakename)+
  labs(y="Concentration(ug/l)",x="year")+ scale_color_manual(name="Legend",labels = c("(No3+No2)-N_wet","NH4_wet"), values = c("purple","blue"))
```

warning message

> Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for
>   'colour', which will replace the existing scale.

New ggplot is replacing my old ggplot instead of overlaying it. I want to have different color so that I can see the change

My data looks like that:

```
lakename    date    variable    value
BM  1/11/2005   no3no2  16
BM  1/14/2011   no3no2  617
BM  1/15/1998   no3no2  27
BM  10/17/2005  no3no2  NaN
BM  10/18/2011  no3no2  0
CR  10/20/1998  no3no2  NaN
CR  10/3/2011   no3no2  NaN
CR  10/5/1998   no3no2  0
FL  10/5/2005   no3no2  0.33
FL  11/1/2011   no3no2  NaN
```

Comment: Did you forget to add the "overlay" to the plot, `g`?  It's missing in your code (i.e., `g + geom_line...`).

Comment: @aesmith. I added g+ and now it is giving me this warning.Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for
'colour', which will replace the existing scale.    I don't know why i can't have both plots at the same time with different color to see the change over different year. Now plot is working but it is not overlayed. g+geom_line line is replacing my old plot and creating a new one rather than overlying it. I edited my question

Comment: You can't have two separate color scales.  It looks like your color scale isn't about "variable" but should be based on "variable:year".  Adding a column to represent year and then stacking your two datasets together  so you can use `color = variable:year` is one option.  You could also use a different aesthetic like `linetype` to display the lines from the second year.